# SVN move directory, does not delete the directory from its initial location on my drive

Tags: svn

I don't know how to word it, so I go with an example :

Here are my directories and files :

```
|-Dir1/
   |-.svn/
   |-file1
   |-file2
|-NewDir/
   |-.svn/
```

I want to make `Dir1` a subdirectory of `NewDir`. So I do :

```
$ svn mv Dir1 NewDir
```

And now I have

```
|-Dir1/
   |-.svn/
|-NewDir/
   |-.svn/
   |-Dir1/
      |-.svn/
      |-file1
      |-file2
```

Why did it move the files but copied the directory ? How do I delete the origin directory properly ?

And moreover, `$ svn status` marks Dir1 as deleted, why is it still here ? Do I simply delete it on my filesystem ( `rm -rf Dir1` )? If yes, is there a less annoying method, so that moving something doesn't require me to manually delete everything I moved ?

Details :
I'm on linux,

```
$ svn --version 
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
compiled Aug 13 2014, 20:46:49
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Using the svn command to make a move does 2 thing :

- It tells svn that files have been moved, so he can retrieve their previous revision
- It moves the files.

Here you'll notice that you have a folder called .svn which is remaining in you folder 1. This is the place where it tells svn that the files have been removed.

You should check you local repository status with the command `svn status`. It should tell you something like this :

```
D Dir1
D Dir1/file1
D Dir1/file2
A Newdir/dir1
A Newdir/dir1/file1
A Newdir/dir1/file2
```

If it does, then it worked, and you just have to commit to see the changes.

Comment: You mean once commited, `Dir1` will eventually be deleted on my drive ?

Comment: what does you `svn status` say ?
When you made the move command, was Newdir already under version control ?

Comment: exactly what you posted. But since commits are immediatly pushed on the server (yay svn!) I don't want to commit until I'm done being all I need to. But I would like `Dir1` to physically disappear otherwise it's a mess.

Comment: I'm not sure you can since the .svn file will probably be used to tell the repository what it needs to move.
You should try doing the same thing on a new local repo and check if it behaves as you want